# ffmpeg rotate problem

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg, rotate, audio-sync

I'm trying to rotate mp4 videos with ffmpeg. Couple of videos succesfuly rotated but one. The problem is audio out sync for entire video. I also used an ios app which was succesful to rotate. Have any idea what's wrong?

This is the code i've used for:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1, fps=30" -vcodec libx265 -crf 10 -acodec copy output.mp4
```

Other codes that i've used were also gave me same result:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1, fps=30" -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1, fps=30" -acodec copy output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -crf 10 -b:v 600k output.mp4
```

version:

```
ffmpeg 2.6.8
```

I think problem is the youtube-dl, This is the video i'm trying to rotate:
https://www.pscp.tv/22dakika/1ZkKzlXkOMoJv

**UPDATE**

The problem was a broken video. I removed the first 30 secs of the video. After that, rotation process gave me a succesful output.

Answer (score 0):

[Update your `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and then run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

It will automatically properly rotate the video.

Comment: Version 3.2.4 Version git-2017-01-22-f1214ad  are both not worked

Comment: I've tried version 3.3. it wasn't worked also. all 3 versions gave me same result, which is a video hasn't rotated.

Comment: @OzanTemel Can you show your command and the resulting, complete console output? You can edit your question with this info.

Comment: Logs aren't available yet but i've added the video link. When i tried to download with youtube-dl i think packets have lost. That could be the reason why ffmpeg can't rotate succesfully